# How to make a website user manual?

Tags: web, html, user-manual

I have this project on my HMI(human machine interface) class and our prof want us to do a user manual for a website, and I'm not sure what a user manual is. I searched online and what I've seen is that a user manual should explain the different buttons on a site and how to navigate, but I'm still not sure I taught a user manual was composed of diagrams that show the website's web pages.

Answer (score 1):

When u install a camera app in your smart phone or YouTube, when you launch it for the first time you get some indications about some buttons and their new download button (YouTube) it's similar to that

Just redirect a webpage to another one using javascript where it shows the instructions and a continue button to redirect it to the mainpage

Hope it helps, all the best.

Comment: Thanks in our case we have to make a document for our website(another project), so it's basically explaining the website features and how to use it which does not involve any diagram.